# How to get the structure of a GDBM database

Tags: database, file-format, gdbm

Modem Manager GUI creates a database named `sms.gdbm` to store all the SMS details. Currently Modem Manager GUI is not providing a feature to simply delete all received/sent messages. So I'm trying to create a program to remove those records from its database (`sms.gdbm`). But first I want to know the structure of the `sms.gdbm` database. What are the databases it contains, also table and their column names. So are there any CLI or GUI programs to display the structure of a `*.gdbm` file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

GDBM databases are readable through the GDBM API. They are basically a way to store simple key-value pairs of any kind. There is no "structure" as in traditional DBMSes : no tables, no columns... Only keys and values.

The API defines the following functions:

```
GDBM_FILE gdbm_open (const char *name, int block_size, int flags, int mode, void (*fatal_func)(const char *));
void gdbm_close (GDBM_FILE dbf);

typedef struct {
    char *dptr;
    int dsize;
} datum;

int gdbm_store (GDBM_FILE dbf, datum key, datum content, int flag);
datum gdbm_fetch (GDBM_FILE dbf, datum key);
int gdbm_delete (GDBM_FILE dbf, datum key);
datum gdbm_firstkey (GDBM_FILE dbf);
datum datum gdbm_nextkey (GDBM_FILE dbf, datum prev);

const char * gdbm_strerror (gdbm_error errno);
```

Basically, all you have to do is open the file through the API...

```
GDBM_FILE database = gdbm_open("sms.gdbm", 512, GDBM_READER, 0, NULL);
```

And start reading:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <gdbm.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    GDBM_FILE database = gdbm_open("sms.gdbm", 512, GDBM_READER, 0, NULL);

    datum key, data;
    for(key = gdbm_firstkey(database); /* get the first key */
        key.dptr != NULL; /* keep going until the end */
        key = gdbm_nextkey(database, key)) /* next key */
    {
        /* fetch data associated to key */
        data = gdbm_fetch(database, key);
        if(data.dptr != NULL)
            printf("Entry found (%d bytes) : %s.\n", data.dsize, data.dptr);
    }
    
    gdbm_close(database);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Be careful that there is no certainty as to the type of data stored in the database. Here, I assumed there would be strings, but it could be *anything*. The data is stored in binary form, and the only thing you can be certain of is the size (`data.dsize`). The API will provide you with a pointer to the start of the data (`data.dptr`), but how you process it is up to you (or at least, up to your *Modem Manager GUI*).

Once you've found the entry you want to delete, just call `gdbm_delete`:

```
gdbm_delete(database, key);
```

And don't forget to close everything when you're done ;)

```
gdbm_close(database);
```

I am not aware of any GDBM reader program already available, but writing one doesn't really require too much effort. Don't forget to include the GDBM header (`gdbm.h`) and to link the library when compiling:

```
gcc reader.c -o reader -lgdbm
```

Comment: There is a command-line tool *gdbm_dump* as part of GDBM for reading all entries: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/gdbm_dump.1.html